Three sides of a quadrilateral are congruent, and their two included angles are right. Must the quadrilateral be a square?
If quadrilateral $ABCD$ has $\angle ABC = \angle DCB = 90^\circ$ and $AB=BC=CD=4$, must $ABCD$ be a square?
Logically, it seems $ABCD$ must be a square, but how can it be proven that $AD$ must be perpendicular to both $AB$ and $DC$ and that it has length $4$?

Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral (I assume the OP means the right angles to be properly oriented for this assumption) in which the opposite sides $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ are given to be congruent and parallel. Draw diagonal $\overline{BD}$ and note that $\angle ABD$ is congruent with its alternate interior partner $\angle CDB$. Therefore $\triangle ABD$ is congruent with $\triangle CDB$ via SAS, and then the corresponding sides $\overline{DA}$ and $\overline{BC}$ are congruent. Having both pairs of opposite sides congruent certifies the quadrilateral is a parallelogram.
Therefore with the specified right angles and congruent sides, your quadrilateral must be a parallelogram, which then clearly must be a square.

Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral.
If a pair of opposite sides are parallel and equal in length, then it is a parallelogram.
If one angle is $90^{\circ}$, then it is a rectangle.
If pair of consecutive sides are equal in length, then it is a square.
OR
Draw diagonal $AC$ then $\angle ACD=45^{\circ}$ then applying cosine theorem in $\triangle ACD$
$AD^2=4^2+(4\sqrt2)^2-2\times 4 \times 4\sqrt2 \cos45^{\circ}$
$AD=4$
It is a square.
OR
Draw diagonal $AC$ then
$\angle ACB=\angle ACD=45^{\circ}$
$AC=AC$
$AB=CD=4$
$\triangle ABC\cong  \triangle ADC$
then $BC=AD=4$

Here too, having one pair of sides congruent and parallel implies a parallelogram only if we assume the qyadrilateral is convex. If the quadrilateral is self-crossing, the two triangles intended to be congruent in my proof are not properly specified to apply SAS.
